# Database design for various objects

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have application where users can create/update info about different objects (flats, rooms, houses, lands, etc.)

Every type of object has different set of parameters.

I see to solutions:

1. Store all info inside one table

   `id,title,object_type,rooms_count,house_floors_count,land_area,flat_area, description, etc..`
   **Pros**: fast search (because every column has correct datatype, rooms_count - integer, description - text)
   **Cons**: huge denormalization
2. Store info inside different tables
   objects: id,title,object_type,price
   object_params: id, param_title, param_type(integer,text,float,etc.)
   object_param_values: id_param,id_object,value (column of type `text`)
   **Pros**: denormalization, frontend guarantees that when `object_type='flat'`, then only parameters for `flat` are shown to user (in `1.` it works like this too)
   **Cons**: `value` in `object_param_values` has type `text` what is bad for speed.

Comment: See questions related to the EAV tag I added.

Answer (score 0):

There's a third option, use two tables.

One table to store the basics of the object:
id, title, object_type

Another table to store the parameters:
id, object_id (from the previous table), parameter, data